# how to receive UDP packets continuously

Tags: udp, continuous

I want to receive UDP packets continuously from the port. I'm using recvfrom() to receive packets. How to put delay after receiving a single packet. I want to receive more than 50 packets. For that I need help. Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is the relevance of the delay?

Answer (score 0):

The network stack captures all packets addressed to the socketaddress on the line for you and puts it in a queue. Just use recvfrom to read the queued data. If you want you application to wait for the next receive event you can use the select function.